# Calculate leaflet map view port

Tags: leaflet, maps

I have view port bounding coordinates (NE(7.48855,80.3641) and SW (7.46907, 80.30747)). Also I have view port height(867px) and width(1866). I calculated zoom and center point to get complete view of above bounds. I used https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/ to make logic. With my calculation i got zoom 14 for height and 15 for width.

```
const getNumberOfSeconds = (decimal) =>{
 const degrees =  Math.floor(decimal);
 const minutes = Math.floor(60 * (decimal - degrees));
 const seconds = 3600 * (decimal - degrees) - 60 * minutes;
 return (degrees * 3600 + minutes *60+ seconds)
}

export const getViewPort = (bound, height,width) =>{
 const tileWidth = 256.;
 const latDiff = Math.abs(bound.maxLat - bound.minLat)
 const latDiffSeconds = getNumberOfSeconds(latDiff);
 const zoom1_2n = (180 * 3600 * height) / (tileWidth * latDiffSeconds);
 const zoom1 = Math.floor(Math.log10(zoom1_2n) / Math.log10(2));

 const lonDiff = Math.abs(bound.maxLng - bound.minLng)
 const lonDiffSeconds = getNumberOfSeconds(lonDiff);
 const zoom2_2n = (360 * 3600 * width) / (tileWidth * lonDiffSeconds);
 const zoom2 = Math.floor(Math.log10(zoom2_2n) / Math.log10(2));
 const center = [0.5 * (bound.maxLat + bound.minLat), 0.5 * (bound.maxLng + bound.minLng)]
 const zoom = Math.min(zoom1, zoom2)
 const newViewPort = { center, zoom }

 return newViewPort;
}
```

Then I get the minimum zoom level which is 14. 
My question is with zoom level 15, map can show above bound. I think I have done mistake at calculation. Please help me to find that, or let me help to calculate zoom value.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-getboundszoom

Comment: Thank you, I can get your idea to work. It calculates zoom as 15.Do you have any idea, where did I do the mistake in calculations?

Comment: You're working in EPSG:4326 but should be working in either EPSG:3857 or screen-relative coordiantes.